# validate start date and end date in laravel 5 using request class

Tags: laravel-5

This is my request class rules.

```
'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
'endDate' => 'date|before:event_cals,eventDate',
```

There I want to verify whether endDate is after the eventDate. It is working properly except when endDate is similar to eventDate. But I want to make sure that there must be able to add an endDate which is similar to eventDate also. For an example if the eventDate is 03/04/2016, there can be able to add an endDate as 03/04/2016 or any upcoming date. But from above rule 03/04/2016 is invalid as an endDate. Is there any keyword for before or equal? Please can any one help me figure out this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new variable taking eventDate minus one and compare endDate with that variable. If eventDate is 12 Feb, eventDate minus one day will be 11 Feb and endDate should be after 11 Feb, which is 12 Feb or later.

Comment: How to declare that variable?